# UR22MKII very low microphone level problem

Tags: audacity, levels, steinberg

I have a Steinberg UR22MKII and in the first input I have a condenser microphone, 48V phantom power is on. When I listen with headphones to the direct monitor, it sounds fine. When I listen with headphones to the DAW (Audacity) setting, it sounds fine. Pretty much all dials are at 12 o'clock.

But when I record in Audacity, the level visually just barely is above the flat line. I had to use the Audicity amplify plugin against the output or else it would sound too quiet when I play back through computer speakers and not the Steinberg to my headphones.

Is this normal? I would think I don't need to do the amplification. If I crank the gain on the Steinberg it causes breakup and static and sounds bad.

I'm using port 2 with other software to record guitar, seems fine.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If it's loud enough via direct monitoring, and loud enough when listening in Audacity, it sounds like there's just a output level difference between your Steinberg interface and your built in computer audio.

Some possible issues:

- Microphone Gain turned down in Audacity
- Waveform vertically zoomed out in Audacity
- Master level of computer audio in the Windows Sound Mixer is turned down

Answer (score 0):

What is your volume output level set to (in other words, do you have your headphones turned up loud?)

When recording, "sounding fine" isn't necessarily good enough; you need to focus on properly using the gain stages in your system. In general this means making sure the input level is correct *before* setting the output level. In other words, make sure the meters are displaying proper signal (not too much either!) and then turn the volume knob on your headphones to a comfortable listening setting.

This is important for many reasons, but the one of the primary reasons is "signal to noise ratio", or how much noise/"hiss" ends up in your final mix.

Gain stages require much more study and [this](http://www.soundonsound.com/techniques/gain-staging-your-daw-software) might be a good place to start, but the important part is to study the subject.